# Using alt+r in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make spokes for a wheel and when I used 2.79 I used alt+r to automatically duplicate and rotate the mesh to make the amount I wanted but this shortcut doesn't work in 2.8. Does anyone know how to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The *Spin* tool still exists in Blender 2.8, you can find it in the toolbar. It does not have a shortcut in the default keymap. You would have to add it yourself or use the 2.7x keymap.

[image: Icon]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

The hotkey in 2.8 is now Shift + r or use the Edit > Repeat Last menu entry.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It just repeats the last operation, while the question is how to use the spin tool.